# Binding View to ViewModel with constructor arguments when no DataTemplate is defined

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How can I bind a View to a ViewModel with constructor arguments when no DataTemplate is defined?

I'm basically trying to bind a `TreeView` control to its data-source.

#### BrowserView.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <TreeView 
        x:Name="StatusTree"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Status, Mode=OneTime}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}"
    />
</UserControl>
```

#### BrowserViewModel.cs

```
public class BrowserNewViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    public BrowserNewViewModel(string name)
    {
        this.DisplayName = name;
    }

    public List<TreeViewModel> Status
    { ... }
}
```

The following describes how I'm instantiating the ViewModel. I'm using the `WorkspaceViewModel` interface as per *Josh Smith's* [MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). `TreeViewModel` is [explained here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView).

#### MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
void DisplayBrowser()
{
    BrowserViewModel browserViewModel = new BrowserViewModel("Browser");
    this.AddTab(browserViewModel);
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4359861/640378) describes a similar scenario, but the answer won't work for me because I don't have an explicit reference to the `UserControl` in the `MainWindow`.

I know I cannot define a `DataTemplate` in the MainWindow's `Resources` because the BrowserViewModel has a constructor with an argument.

There are other solutions that require the use of a framework. Is there simple way of **avoiding using a framework**?

Comment: Easy answer: Can you add an empty constructor?

Comment: @Shlomo Does it mean that I can use a `DataTemplate` for rendering the ViewModel and the `UserControl.Binding` property to set the `DataContext`? I ask because it appears as if **2 different instances of the View** would be created (because there are 2 constructors now). I haven't been able to get it to work yet, probably because I'm not setting the `Status` property right (new to C#; but, I'll figure this out).