# How to handle making a Window in WPF (C#) that takes parameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using WPF (C#) for the first time and this I've encountered my first "real" design choice. I have a main window and when the user enters some data and presses the "plot" `Button`, a new window will come up showing a graph.

This graph window I am defining myself with a combination of xaml and the code-behind file. The issue is that 2 parameters this window has is the x axis title and the y axis title. So, these should be "parameters" to making this window.

I am confused by this because I'm using MVVM and I have a "ViewModel" for the window called `GraphWindowPresenter` and a "View" for the class called `GraphWindowView`.

At first, I tried to have an `xAxis` property and a `yAxis` property in my `GraphWindowPresenter` but that will not work since I need to "bind" to these values upon construction of the `GraphWindowView`. Additionally, this approach would require that my `GraphWindowPresenter` take an `xAxis` parameter and a `yAxis` parameter which is problamatic as well since I just create an instance of the class in the xaml of `GraphWindowView`.

I'm thinking of a possible soltuion that I can just have my `GraphWindowView` take the `xAxis` and `yAxis` parameters but doesn't this violate MVVM? I would rather not do that.

**Note:** This is similar to this post [MVVM: Binding a ViewModel which takes constructor args to a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359861/mvvm-binding-a-viewmodel-which-takes-constructor-args-to-a-usercontrol). But in my scenario it is tricky since I have a parent window and a pop up child window.

**Question:** What is the best approach to this design issue? What are the "best practices" regarding this scenario?

**Possible Answer:**

Is this the correct use of dependency properties that you described? Is this a "clean" solution?

```
private void doGraph()
{
    if (log == null) // if a log is not loaded
    {
        MessageBoxResult mbr = MessageBox.Show("A log file must be " +
                                               "loaded before plotting.",
                                               "Warning",
                                               MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                               MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        return;
    }

    // NOW MUST PRESENT GRAPH WINDOW
    GraphWindowView gwv = new GraphWindowView();
    gwv.xAxis = X_AXIS_VALUE:
    gwv.yAxis = Y_AXIS_VALUE;
    gwv.Show();
}
```

And in my `GraphWindowView` class I have the code:

```
public partial class GraphWindowView : Window
{
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for yAxis.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty yAxisProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("yAxis", typeof(string), typeof(GraphWindowView));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for xAxis.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty xAxisProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("xAxis", typeof(string), typeof(GraphWindowView));

    public string xAxis
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(xAxisProperty); }
        set { SetValue(xAxisProperty, value); }
    }

    public string yAxis
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(yAxisProperty); }
        set { SetValue(yAxisProperty, value); }
    }

    public GraphWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: MVVM is all about separating business logic from UI concerns.  It isn't about removing codebehind.  If all the window needs is an x and y axis value, expose them as dependency properties on a type extending Window and be done.  No need to sweat.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have been reading a lot on dependency properites, but I do not fully understand them. Could you expand on how they will help me in *this* scenario I explained and maybe that will shed some light on their usefulness? Thanks again!

Comment: You'd use a DP because it's being defined on a UI type and would possibly participate in binding (if not from the outside, then from within the window definition itself, e.g., controls in your custom window).  You can INPC it as well, but DP is usually the way to go for UI elements.  DependencyProperties are just POCO properties that use the binding infrastructure for storage.  DPs are the fastest binds available in WPF and come with a bunch of other benefits.  Yeah, a bit odd at the start, but I use em all the time.

Comment: Oh, OK. So am I just using these basically as regular static properties of a class? I added my resulting code snippet above (per your recommendation). Is this the correct way to handle this? Simply use them as static fields...? BTW, this code is in my ViewModel for my main parent window called `MainWindowPresenter`. Can this also be done/better in xaml?

Comment: The DP pattern is much more complex than just "static fields".  You can read all about it on MSDN; there is a pretty good article about them that you can easily find.  And, yeah, UI concerns should not be handled in your VM, strictly speaking.

Comment: Wouldn't the axis titles be considered part of the business logic? They're certainly not UI elements and yet you've stuck them in as part of the view. I struggled with this as well and ended up sending the new window's context in through the constructor and set it there as the DataContext (after I decided I was tired of searching for the "appropriate" way to do it -- whatever that might be).

Comment: @Will Yes, I know they are much more than static fields in terms of capability, etc. but I am talking about the usage in how I am using them above. i.e. I'm asking the question: is the code I posted using the DP the way you meant when you told me to use them?

Comment: @user3703862: Is there a problem?

Comment: No, there is not. I'm just asking is that what you meant / is that good design? That is why I asked the question to get a feel for design. So yes it works, but is that good design / are there better alternatives? @bdimag did raise a point, that's why I'm asking. Either way though, thanks for the help so far you've been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can you userSetting properties

One my application have same scenario in that i have mainWindow that accept HostAddress,Port value and it will use another window when i click connect so i am using userSetting properties. I am also using MVVM pattern check code snippet below

```
XAML:
<TextBox Width="120" Canvas.Left="132" Canvas.Top="16" Text="{Binding Path=Server,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Width="120" Canvas.Left="132" Canvas.Top="42" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayPort,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Width="120" Canvas.Left="132" Canvas.Top="69" Text="{Binding Path=CtrlPort,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button Content="Launch" Name="btnLaunch" Command="{Binding Path=appSetting}" Canvas.Left="132" Canvas.Top="100" Width="120" Height="51" Click="btnLaunch_Click" />

VIEWMODE:
public class SettingsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Settings _settings { get; set; }

    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        appSetting = new RelayCommand(this.AppSettingsCommand);
        _settings = ApplicationTest.Properties.Settings.Default;
    }

    private string _server = Settings.Default.Server;
    public string Server
    {
        get { return this._server; }
        set
        {
            if (this._server != value)
            {
                this._server = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Server");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _displayPort = Settings.Default.DisplayPort;
    public string DisplayPort
    {
        get { return this._displayPort; }
        set
        {
            if (this._displayPort != value)
            {
                this._displayPort = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DisplayPort");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _ctrlPort = Settings.Default.CtrlPort;
    public string CtrlPort
    {
        get { return this._ctrlPort; }
        set
        {
            if (this._ctrlPort != value)
            {
                this._ctrlPort = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DisplayPort");
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand appSetting
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void AppSettingsCommand()
    {
        this._settings.Server = this.Server;
        this._settings.DisplayPort = this.DisplayPort;
        this._settings.CtrlPort = this.CtrlPort;
        this._settings.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see what you're saying, but these properites arent really "user settings". They're not actually something that the user specifically sets. I see how this solution would work, but I do not this it is the optimal. Would you agree, or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: You can set value in viewmodel you can find all properties will set what user will give in main connect window. Can you please tell me from where xAxis and yAxis values comes in your scenario?

Comment: My xAxis and yAxis come from a condition which is set by a set of radio buttons.